# How to use Intel PT to check if a conditional branch is taken in assembly?

Tags: assembly, intel, control-flow-graph

I am running a program and I want to check whether a branch is taken when there is a conditional jump.

I heard that IntelPT can do that using  `pt_qry_cond_branch()` function. However I could not see any example on how to use it. Does anyone have any idea about it?

For example, how would I use Intel PT to see what happened in this function:

```
foo:
    rdrand  eax
    cmp     eax, 1<<29
    ja    .taken
    nop
.taken:
    xor     eax, eax
    ret
```

I want to know how to use Intel-PT for this, rather than setting a breakpoint on the `nop` or some other way of instrumenting to find the data and compute the branch condition myself.

Answer (score 1):

It should be straight-forward to see in the instruction trace that you can record with IntelPT-support, e.g. through `perf` on Linux. You will either see the `nop` in the trace or not. I'm not sure what [`pt_qry_cond_branch()`](https://github.com/01org/processor-trace/blob/master/doc/man/pt_qry_cond_branch.3.md) could contribute -- isn't it just part of the trace decoder library that will post-process a recorded trace?